# Extend application User_Model with module-specific subclass

Tags: php, kohana

In kohana 2.3.4 system load first application, after modules and system. I want to extends User_Model in application with User_Model in modules. How to do that?

---

Kohana loads:

1. application
2. modules
3. system

I want to extend User_Model in application, with User_Model in modules.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Application overrides modules and system.  I would advise you restructure you inheritance.  Model functionality shouldn't depend on the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't extends user_model (application) with user_model (modules), but you can use another name for your model then extends the user_model.